# How to post multiple select values in MVC 3 with Chosen jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

how do I post the selected values in MVC 3 using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) jquery plugin. I don't get how to post the values I selected. This is how my code looks so far..
[image: my test page]

Here is my post form with the selectlist and a submit button that posts to my controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{        
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Category..." class="chzn-select" multiple style="width: 650px;" tabindex="4">
        <option value=""></option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
        {
            <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option> 
        }
    </select><br/>
    <button type="submit" value="Search" name="button">Search</button>
}
```

This is my model that I'm using.

```
 public class CategoryModel
{
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public CategoryModel()
    {
        Categories = new List<Category>();

        Category cat = new Category();
        cat.Id = 1;
        cat.Name = "Ekonomi";
        Categories.Add(cat);

        cat = new Category();
        cat.Id = 2;
        cat.Name = "IT";
        Categories.Add(cat);

        cat = new Category();
        cat.Id = 3;
        cat.Name = "Teknik";
        Categories.Add(cat);
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So how do I retrive the values from the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the comments will be added as parameters to the function, so, in the controller:

```
Function Index(Optional sortOrder As String = "", Optional searchString As String = "", Optional page As Integer = 1) As ViewResult
```

And in the view:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm()

    @<p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter)  
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>

End Using
```

You can also send parameters via URL:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParam})
```

Note:  This is VB.

Answer (score 0):

1. Name your select Tag ex: "naicsCodeSelect"
2. In controller use int[] "Tagname" i.e:int[] naicsCodeSelect
   see the below example:

In View:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("naicsCodeSelect", ViewBag.selectNAICS as    List<SelectListItem>, new { @multiple = "true", @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 chosen-select" })
```

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Industry model, int[] naicsCodeSelect)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {}
```